# Getting short path for ssh

Tags: bash, ssh, sh, pwd, tilde-expansion

I'm writing a shell script to be used with ssh/git.

I want to get the present directory relative to home, if possible.

The goal is to get the shortest path to be used with ssh, that is the path in context of the user.

For example, if my working directory was `/home/jon/folder/other`, and I was user `jon` with `$HOME` being `/home/jon`, I would get (`~/`)`folder/other` from the command. Tilde-slash between the parentheses optional.

So then I could give my user the instruction to use ssh at `jon@server:folder/other` instead of longer `jon@server:/home/jon/folder/other`.

Is there are trivial way to do this (which I'm feeling there is) or do I need a script to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
${PWD#$HOME/}
```

The `bash` operation `${string#substring}` strips `substring` from the front of `$string` (if it matches).

This might help you with future questions about `bash`: [Recommended online resources for learning bash scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/855464/1380680)